# Symmetric sum of $n$-th residues modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

There is a result of Pierce (see [here](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1026&context=mathfacpub)) which states:

Let $p\ge 3$ be a prime, and fix $n,k$ positive integers such that there exactly $2k$ non-zero $n$-th residues modulo $p$. Then
$$
\sum (x_1\cdots x_k)^2 \equiv 2(-1)^{k-1} \bmod{p},
$$
where the sum is taken over all pairwise distinct $n$-residues $x_1,\ldots,x_k$.

In particular, if the order matters then the above result would be multiplied by a factor $k!$. Here, I would ask for a generalization. Is it possible to prove in a similar way the following one?

> **Question.** Let $p\ge 3$ be a prime, and fix $n,k$ positive integers such that there exactly $2k$ non-zero $n$-th residues modulo $p$. Fix also positive integers $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ with sum $2k$. Then
>   $$
> \sum x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_k^{a_k} \equiv 2(-1)^{k-1}k! \bmod{p},
> $$
>   where the sum is taken over all pairwise distinct $n$-residues $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ (counting the permutations).